# how to implement drag text on canvas in android

Tags: android, canvas, android-edittext, drag

i have a canvas in which i add text from alert dialog box now i want to drag that text on canvas.here is the code for alertdialogbox and how i drag my text on canvas but drag code is not working.so ans plzz...

```
     AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(c_new);
                    final EditText editText = new EditText(c_new);

                    builder1.setTitle("Edit Text");
                    builder1.setMessage("Enter Your Text Here.");
                    builder1.setView(editText);
                    // builder1.setCancelable(true);

                    builder1.setPositiveButton(
                            "Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    srt = editText.getText().toString();
                                    c.setEdittext(srt);

                                    click_values c1 = new click_values();
                                    c1.setImage(3);
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    builder1.setNegativeButton(
                            "Cancle",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder1.create();
                    alertDialog.show();




                pointerId2 = event.getPointerId(actionIndex);

                touchedText = mCirclePointer2.get(pointerId2);

 if (null != touchedText) {
                    touchedText.centerX = xTouch -xTouch1 / 2;
                    touchedText.centerY = yTouch -yTouch1 / 2;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library, [android-StickerView](https://github.com/kencheung4/android-StickerView)

To add a draggable text,

```
// add a stickerText to canvas
StickerTextView tv_sticker = new StickerTextView(getContext());
tv_sticker.setText(“Hello World!”);
canvas.addView(tv_sticker);
```